# C++ map, find the first element that is less than key

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree

I am currently looking for a data structure that is similiar to map in C++.

I am looking for a function that can return first element which is immediately less than a certain number. for example:

```
map<int,int> m;
m[1] ++;
m[2] ++;
m[4] ++;
m[5] ++;

find_first_element_less_than(3) ----> return 2; 
m.upper_bound(3) ---> return 4;
```

I have looked at the `lower_bound` function. However, it says it returns the first element not less than key. In this case, lower_bound(3) returns 4. which is not what I want.

I am wondering if there is any data structure in C++ that can do this for me?

---

## UpdatE:

Can I do `auto it = m.lower_bound(3);  if (it != m.begin()) it--;`??

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want find the *last* element whose key is less than the argument? (And do you want the function to return the value, or the key, or an iterator, or what?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the lower bound and then decrement the iterator by 1 if it is not pointing to the beginning of the map.

Answer (score 11):

I think you could do this by reversing the order of your map (`map<int,int, std::greater<int> > m;`) and then using `upper_bound` to find the first item "greater" (but really less because you inverted the predicate) than the requested item. If you need to iterate in ascending order you'll have to use reverse iterators which may be slightly confusing to maintainers (including yourself). Carefully consider your needs with regards to this possible solution.

Comment: This is a great solution, if the order can be reversed with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

*lower_bound* return an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than (i.e. **greater or equal to**) key. so, it's so better that use *upper_bound* and always decrease the iterator:

```
int find_first_element_less_than(int val)
{
    auto uppper_node = m.upper_bound(val);
    if (uppper_node != m.begin())
        uppper_node--;

    return upuppper_node->second;
}
```